# Pagination for WP Query not working

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I am creating pagination for a custom template in WordPress and keep getting a 404 when clicking all other pages besides Page 1. I am able to successfully get paginated links for each page, but as mentioned, keeps returning a 404.

Here's the function I'm calling for pagination which lives in functions.php:

```
function custom_page_navi( $totalpages, $page, $end_size, $mid_size )
{
    $bignum = 999999999;

    if ( $totalpages <= 1 || $page > $totalpages ) return;

        //NOTE: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links
    return paginate_links( array(
        'total'         => $totalpages,
        'prev_next'     => false,
        'type'          => 'list',
        'show_all'      => false,
        'end_size'      => $end_size,
        'mid_size'      => $mid_size
    ) );
}
```

Here is the code living in taxonomy-pagename.php:

```
<?php

$this_page_taxonomy = $wp_query->get_queried_object(); //getting this page terms
$current_slug = $this_page_taxonomy->slug; //current slug
$go_cpt = 'hope_go'; //taxonony  name
$number = 1; // number of terms to display per page

// Setup for pagination:

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$offset = ($paged > 0) ? $number * ($paged - 1) : 1;
$totalposts = $this_page_taxonomy->count;
$totalpages = ceil($totalposts / $number);

$hope_go_args = array(
 'post_type' => $go_cpt,
 'orderby' => 'meta_value',
 'meta_key' => 'hope_go_series_date',
 'meta_value' => $time,
 'meta_compare' => '>=',
 'paged' => $paged,
 'order' => 'ASC',
 'posts_per_page' => $number,
 'hierarchical' => true,
 'offset' => $offset,
 'tax_query' => array(
    array(
    'taxonomy' => 'hope_go_series',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => $current_slug,
    ) ,
)
);

$hope_go_recent_posts = new WP_Query($hope_go_args);

if ($hope_go_recent_posts->have_posts()):

  while ($hope_go_recent_posts->have_posts()):
  $hope_go_recent_posts->the_post();

    printf('<nav class="recent-series__pagination">%s</nav>',
    custom_page_navi($totalpages, $paged, 3, 0) < ? php

    //Content would go here

  endwhile;

?>

<?php

else : ?>

    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?> </p>

<?php
endif;

wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

I tried a rewrite but that was not the problem. It seems as if all pages except Page 1 can't pull in the corresponding posts. Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**Please go through the below steps to get pagination**

Simply add the following codes in your template **functions.php** or add the scripts where ever you need the pagination.

**Step-1**

```
$customPagHTML     = "";
$query             = "SELECT * FROM custom_table";
$total_query     = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (${query}) AS combined_table";
$total             = $wpdb->get_var( $total_query );
$items_per_page = 4;
$page             = isset( $_GET['cpage'] ) ? abs( (int) $_GET['cpage'] ) : 1;
$offset         = ( $page * $items_per_page ) - $items_per_page;
$result         = $wpdb->get_results( $query . " ORDER BY field DESC LIMIT ${offset}, ${items_per_page}" );
$totalPage         = ceil($total / $items_per_page);
```

Then above script have “custom_table” that you need to replace with your table name also you have option to add ORDER BY or GROUP BY etc. Then just iterate the “$result” that have your query result

**Step-2**

```
if($totalPage > 1){
$customPagHTML     =  '<div><span>Page '.$page.' of '.$totalPage.'</span>'.paginate_links( array(
'base' => add_query_arg( 'cpage', '%#%' ),
'format' => '',
'prev_text' => __('&laquo;'),
'next_text' => __('&raquo;'),
'total' => $totalPage,
'current' => $page
)).'</div>';
}
```

**Step-3**

```
echo $customPagHTML;
```

Then simply output the $customPagHTML variable where ever you need the pagination like above.

Comment: thanks! I will try this now, but what do you mean by replace "custom_table" with my table name? How do I get my table name?

Comment: wp_posts table with your post type